# Turn Hex Output into Binary w/Max of 53 bits (0 or 1 values)

Tags: python, binary, hex, bit

I have the following hex output: -0x1.4002000000000p+10

I want to turn that output into its binary form with no more than 53 bits (0 or 1 values).  As such, the desired output is: 1.0100000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000

I tried the following code below:

```
f'{-0x1.4002000000000:0<54b}'
```

But it returns back the following error:

```
File "<fstring>", line 1
    (-0x1.4002000000000)
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't support hex for decimals. "x = 0x1.2" raises and error. You can do it if you drop the decimal place.

```
f'{0x14002:0<54b}'
```

Comment: it worked!  thank you ----------> Questions ----------> can you explain what that 0 is doing? also, 54b means 54 bits of storage?

Comment: also what if my 0x14002 value is stored in a variable --> let's say var.     I tried to do f'{var:0<54b} but the code errored out 

What can I do?

Comment: For the "OBJ:0<54b", the "b" is a special command to run the builtin bin() around OBJ and drop the "0b" part. Likewise the 54 says to make that result 54 characters big, this is done by specifying what character to add "0" and whether to fill that on the left ">" or right "<". The format language for f-strings is a whole mini sub language in python.

Comment: If x=0x14002, then f'{x:0<54b}' does the same thing.

Comment: I am not following what you mean by 54b means 54 bits of storage. A f-string in python returns a string. Each character takes up one byte. The "b" has nothing to do with the storage of the string or how much memory is used. The "b" is a conversion using the built in bin() function.

Comment: when I set x = 0x14002000000000 and then did f'{x:0<54b}', I get the following error: "ValueError: Unknown format code 'b' for object of type 'str'"

Comment: You did NOT set x = 0x14002, you set x = "0x14002" a string. Hence, bin() attempted to run on that string and produced an error. If you set it to the literal hex value (i.e., a python integer), it works.

Comment: oh!  I see do you mean I can do int(0x14002) to set it as a python integer?

Comment: No. 0x14002 is already and integer in python. Wrapping it around int() does nothing. Try: print(0x14002).

Comment: Python understands native standard integer expressions. 0b1111 is the integer 15, likewise 0xFF is the integer 255, and 0o777 is the integer 511.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228502/discussion-between-pinenuts0-and-bobby-ocean).